# Python 3D library in tree generation and light projection

Tags: python, 3d, simulation

I am doing a simulation experiment on how tree grows under different circumstances such as light intensity, leave shape.

Is there a Python 3D library that may facilitate the process of generating a tree with tree leaves(in nature) and with strong light projection support so I can calculate light intensity even considering the shade cast by leaves.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there is a *simple* and *readily available* solution to this, but here are some pointers on how to do this yourself:

1. Watch Vi Hart's [Spirals, Fibonacci and being a
   plant](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ahXIMUkSXX0) videos to learn
   how plants grow.
2. Then use [Blender](http://www.blender.org/)'s[Python
   API](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts) to
   generate 3d models of natural trees.
3. Finally create a
   [Povray](http://www.povray.org/) source file using
   [Python](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/205451/) and trace the
   scene.